# What is the difference between "escasear" and "faltar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-entre-palabras

They both mean "lack" in English. However,is there any difference in the usage? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Escasear' is when there is insufficient amount of something and it's used only with uncountable things. 'Faltar' is closer to 'miss', and it's the only one you can use when there is nothing at all of something.

- Escasea la comida = There isn't enough food
  You could also say:
- Falta comida (uncountable) - There isn't enough food
  but if you say
- Falta la comida (countable), the meaning is The food is missing

You can say:

- Falta un zapato = A shoe is missing
  but you can't say
- Escasea un zapato

Comment: Hi Leo! Can "escasear"use with collective nouns which are countable but used in a general sense ?

Comment: Yes, for example "Escasean los clientes".

Comment: And,Dose the faltar have a more general meaning that can both express there is nothing at all and there has some but the amount isn't enough?

Comment: Correct. On the other hand, escasear means that there is some amount left.

Comment: "Escasea un zapato" it sonds bizarre! Maybe "escasean los zapatos" sound pretty natural!

Comment: Please Davius, read the comment properly. It says: "you can't say escasea un zapato"